# generating the first n terms of the continued fraction expansion of a number

Tags: haskell

***EDIT: @Downvoters:*** Could you at least please tell me how I can improve this question? I tried the best I can, and getting downvotes without any comment is not constructive in my opinion.

Im still new to Haskell, and as an exercises, I'm trying to make function, that returns the first `n` terms of the continued fraction expansion of `x`. The first argument `x` can be a floting point or an integral, the second argument must be an `int`. This is my code so far, which does load without error:

```
continuedFraction x n | x < 0  = []
                      | n < 1 = []
                      | otherwise = [floor x] ++ (take n (continuedFraction (1 / (x - floor x)) (n-1) ) )
```

(I am aware that this is not very elegant, but It was the simplest one I was able to come up with at that point.)

As soon as I actually use the function e.g. `continuedFraction 3.1415 4` I get the error message below. Can anyone point out my error / explain that message?

(I did try to make a type definition with the ideas above, but without success too: `continuedFraction :: (Num x) => x -> Int -> [Integer]`)

The error message (when running without the type definition):

```
*Main> continuedFraction 3.1415 4

<interactive>:86:1:
    Could not deduce (Integral a0)
      arising from a use of `continuedFraction'
    from the context (Integral t)
      bound by the inferred type of it :: Integral t => [t]
      at <interactive>:86:1-26
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      instance Integral Int -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      instance Integral Word -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
    In the expression: continuedFraction 3.1415 4
    In an equation for `it': it = continuedFraction 3.1415 4

<interactive>:86:19:
    Could not deduce (Fractional a0) arising from the literal `3.1415'
    from the context (Integral t)
      bound by the inferred type of it :: Integral t => [t]
      at <interactive>:86:1-26
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral a => Fractional (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      instance Fractional Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Fractional Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
    In the first argument of `continuedFraction', namely `3.1415'
    In the expression: continuedFraction 3.1415 4
    In an equation for `it': it = continuedFraction 3.1415 4
```

Answer (score 3):

### Advice

If you are a beginner at Haskell there are a few rules you should stick to:

- if you have a function, make sure you give it a type signature which expresses your intended input/output
- if in doubt stick to concrete types `Double` over typeclasses `Fractional a`
- if your function is working as intended remove the type signature or use the language extension `-XScopedTypeVariables` and ghci to explore the signatures the compiler would infer to get a feel for typeclasses

### Answer

Now let us explore your function - you want to generate a continued fraction i assume the formula you have written down for generating it is correct. Haskell is powerful enough to model infinite lists so let us use that power and get rid of that second parameter and generate a (possibly) infinite list.

```
continuedFraction :: Double -> [Int]
```

So we see - you are expecting a `Double` input and as a result `[Int]`, i.e. a list of integers, I chose `Int` for simplicity - as for huge `Integer` I don't think this algorithm is neither stable nor efficient - and using `Double`'s I guess the real problem will be floating point arithmetics.

```
continued fraction x | x < 0     = []
                     | otherwise = let i = floor x
                                       x' = 1/(x - fromIntegral i)
                                   in i : continuedFraction x'
```

This is the simplest solution you came up with, the problems you had were

- `i :: Int`, `x :: Double` in Haskell you cannot subtract things of different type, there is no autoboxing/automatic coercion. We like the control over those things - the compiler is **not** smart enough to infer what we 'obviously' wanted to calculate (you see what this leads to if you use MS Excel).
- the solution to this problem is explicit conversion `fromIntegral :: Double -> Int` in this case
- for readability I also switched the `[a] ++` to `a :` which is equivalent, less to write and more performant, but performance is not of concern here

using the function now in ghci: `ghci myfile.hs`

```
> continuedFraction 3.1415
[3,.....] --infinite list
> take 4 $ continuedFraction 3.1415
[3,7,14,1]
```

now you can explore the function!

### How to use the advice

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables#-}

module SO34830462 where

--continuedFraction :: Double -> [Int]
continuedFraction :: Double -> _
continuedFraction x | x < 0  = []
                    | otherwise = let i = floor x
                                      x' = 1/ (x - fromIntegral i)
                                  in i : continuedFraction  x'
```

`ghci myfile.hs` leads to an error

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling SO34830462       ( 34830462.hs, interpreted )

myfile.hs:6:32:
    Found hole ‘_’ with type: [t]
    [...]
               continuedFraction :: Integral t => Double -> [t]
    [...]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

It tells you in short - "oh you didn't specify a correct type signature", but ghc could use this type signature.

you can substitute the type signature and do the same with the `Double` parameter, exploring the function bit by bit.

if you are not sure what to start with you can omit the type signature and call `:t continuedFraction` iside a ghci session.

Comment: btw it would be a good exercise to use a `fold` to get the original fraction back!

Comment: Danke very much for your tips! That would be my next challenge=) Currently I am using learnyouahaskell.com but can you recommend other tutorials?

Comment: Bitte gern geschehen - I don't know what your learing type is - but there is some material here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info and if you are lucky there might be a local meetup group/user group near you (in vienna we are called lambdaheads). Also there are some functional programming university courses out there you can check out.

Answer (score 2):

The Haskell numeric tower strikes again. So general! Yet such obtuse error messages!

```
continuedFraction x n
  | x < 0 || n < 1 =
    []
  | otherwise =
    floor x : take n (continuedFraction (1 / (x - floor x)) (n - 1))
```

So, if you throw this code into an interpreter and then infer the type you get

```
continuedFraction
  :: (Integral a, Integral t, RealFrac a) => a -> Int -> [t]
```

There's a hidden problem here! There's no good way to resolve the two `Integral a, RealFrac a` constraints.

```
λ> :info Integral
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where
   ...
instance Integral Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
λ> :info RealFrac
class (Real a, Fractional a) => RealFrac a where
   ...
instance RealFrac Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance RealFrac Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
```

Integral types by definition aren't fractional types; fractional types by definition aren't integral types. There are ways of converting between the two, of course, but none were invoked here. The obtuseness of GHC's error messages masks this problem.

The problem arises from this expression: `x - floor x`. `floor x` has an integral type, `x` has a fractional type. In order for `(-) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a` to typecheck, we get the impossible `(Integral a, RealFrac a)` constraint.

The solution is to lift `floor x` with `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`.

```
continuedFraction' :: (Integral t, RealFrac a) => a -> Int -> [t]
continuedFraction' x n
  | x < 0 || n < 1 =
    []
  | otherwise =
    floor x : take n (continuedFraction' (1 / decimal) (n - 1))
    where
      decimal = x - fromInteger (floor x)

λ> continuedFraction' 3.14159 4
[3,7,15,1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! I was not aware of the requirement to convert types.